# Set pagination on MaterialTable ui https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/localization?

Tags: reactjs, pagination, material-ui, material-table

That is my code. I would like to set pagination to 50, 100, 250 rows per page (for example). How can I achieve that?

```
 <MaterialTable

        localization={{
          pagination: {
            labelDisplayedRows: '4-6 of 10',
            labelRowsPerPage:'{5, 10, 25,100}'
          },

        }}
        title="Crawler Results"
        columns={[
          { title: "URL", field: "url" },
          { title: "Status", field: "status" }
        ]}
        data={state.data}
        actions={[
          {
            icon: 'add',
            tooltip: 'Add User',
            isFreeAction: true,
            onClick: () => {

              //show crawler table and hide formular
              document.getElementById('formCrawler').style.display = "block";
              document.getElementById('formSpan').style.display = "block";
              document.getElementById('crawlerTableID').style.display = "none";

            }
          }]}
      />
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props), you can override the `pageSizeOptions` in `options` with an array of page sizes.

```
<MaterialTable

    localization={{
      pagination: {
        labelDisplayedRows: '4-6 of 10',
        labelRowsPerPage:'{5, 10, 25,100}'
      },

    }}
    title="Crawler Results"
    columns={[
      { title: "URL", field: "url" },
      { title: "Status", field: "status" }
    ]}
    options={{
        pageSizeOptions : [50, 100, 200]
    }}
    data={state.data}
    actions={[
      {
        icon: 'add',
        tooltip: 'Add User',
        isFreeAction: true,
        onClick: () => {

          //show crawler table and hide formular
          document.getElementById('formCrawler').style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById('formSpan').style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById('crawlerTableID').style.display = "none";

        }
      }]}
  />
```

Comment: Thank you it helped me , i was on that problem about one hour

Comment: Glad I could help , if that fixed your problem, could you mark the answer as accepted so that others can find it ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `labelRowsPerPage` didn't do anything for me.  I added the following property to the `MaterialTable`:

```
options={{
  pageSizeOptions: [50, 100, 250]
}}
```

https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props